# How to access and modify a variable in any file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, global-variables, riverpod

novice in flutter and programming here. It's been few days that I can't find a proper solution to my issue : The thing is I need a variable from my DataWidget, in my MapWidget. But I can't pass it when the widget is called (ex : MapWidget(variable : variable)) because MapWidget isn't called in DataWidget but in main. So I wonder how i could access a variable and modify it from a widget that is same level/higher in the widget Tree ?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sensors Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0x9f4376f8),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (ctx) => DataWidget(),
        MapWidget.routeName: (ctx) => MapWidget()
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to make it a global variable but the value doesnt update when modified so im left with the initial value in my other widgets (it is a GpsPositionValue so its updating continuoulsy) and I was told global variable aren't the best.
I also came across riverpod but didn't fully understood how to access and modify the value accross widgets.I think I need to use StateProviders but fromwhat i saw i can only use it in the Widget build ? Im confuse on how to use it. Hope my english is clear enough

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the updated value from the `DataWidget` class, you can create a provider for it.

As you mentioned Riverpod, it is the easiest way to get its reference and updated value.

Simply, create a provider that returns the instance:

```
final dataWidgetProvider = Provider<DataWidget>((ref) => DataWidget());
```

Convert your `StatefulWidget` into `ConsumerStatefulWidget` and the corresponding `State<MyApp>` to the `ConsumerState<MyApp>`. The **ConsumerState** class automatically gets a `ref` as a property so you can use it to get and watch the value of your desired variable.

```
final dataWidget = ref.watch(dataWidgetProvider);
```

For more, check out Riverpod docs: [Riverpod documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/getting_started)